# WatiN LogonDialogHandler & Windows 2000

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, watin

I'm having trouble logging into a secure site with a WatiN LogonDialogHandler running on a IE6 / Windows 2000 machine.  It doesn't fill in the userid/password for the proxy site, but works fine on a IE7 / Windows XP machine.

**Has anyone ever had/solved this problem?**

I found [the same question on dream.in.code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic74996.htm), but it's unanswered.

I know upgrading to IE7 might solve this problem, but upgrading is not an option right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, forgot I had posted this...I figured out the reason(s) that WatiN wasn't handling logon (or any) dialogs in IE6:

1. The check for the **iexplore.exe** process name was case sensitive.
2. IE6 has a different logon dialog than IE7, so the code to send clicks and text to its controls didn't work.

See the [patch I submitted](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=843730&aid=2831655&group_id=167632) for more info.

Apparently no one else is trying to handle IE6 dialogs with WatiN. Lucky them!